# Remember and autofill last known data

Tags: input, field

I'm makeing a phonegap app for Android. I have some input field where the user can enter text and I want this text to be saved so that it will still be there when opening the app the next time, but still allowed to be changed and then the new text will be remembered instead.

Example:

```
First time open app --> enter text "cat" --> close app
---> second time opening app, text "cat" is already field in
--> user change "cat" to "dog" --> close app
-->open app third time text "dog" is already filled in.
```

So how do I approached this? The only thing I found looking around google is 
autocomplete on/off, but that dose not give the effect I want. Is it even possible?

The app is simple html so just think of it like if it was a normal website. How would I get that effect?

Cheers
Jimmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out localStorage.  It allows you to set key/value pairs that you could store and then call upon at a later date.  The pseudocode would look like this.

App Starts
check if localStorage is available, if so continue
check if value for your textbox is in localStorage(will be nothing yet)
if value is there 
  set text
else 
  User Enters text
store text into localStorage with a key representative of the text box
user closes app

app opens
check if localStorage is available, if so continue
check if value for your textbox is in localStorage(should be set)
if value is there 
  set text

Check out a link here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage#description